# Is it possible to create a mask in an SVG file?

Tags: html, image, svg, mask

I created this SVG, which displays correctly in a web browser.

```html
<svg width="256" height="256">
  <defs>
<g id="maskPath">
  <polygon points="101 50 135 50 135 29 101 29" fill="black" transform="rotate(10, 101, 24)"/>
  <polygon points="121 50 155 50 155 29 121 29" fill="black" transform=" rotate(-10, 155, 24)"/>
</g>
<g id="symmetry" mask="url">
  <polygon points="128 124 116 100 124 100 124 56 132 56 132 100 140 100 128 124"/>
  <polygon points="96 29 160 29 160 24 96 24"/>
  <polygon points="96 24 120 24 120 19 96 19" transform="rotate(100, 96, 24)"/>
  <polygon points="136 24 160 24 160 19 136 19" transform="rotate(-100, 160, 24)"/>
</g>
  </defs>
  <mask id="mask">
<rect width="256" height="256" fill="white"/>
<use href="#maskPath" transform="rotate (0, 128, 128)"/>
<use href="#maskPath" transform="rotate (120, 128, 128)"/>
<use href="#maskPath" transform="rotate (-120, 128, 128)"/>
  </mask>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (0, 128, 128)"/>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (120, 128, 128)"/>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (240, 128, 128)"/>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="56" stroke="black" stroke-width="12" fill-opacity="0"/>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="88" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Image showing the SVG correctly]

However if I change the extension to `.svg` and open it in an SVG viewer, it displays incorrectly. It looks like everything in the `<defs>` and `<mask>` is missing.

[image: Image showing the SVG incorrectly]

Are the `<mask>` and `<defs>` HTML-only tags? The result is similar in other SVG viewers. Is there another way I can cut sections of the circle out?
The green in this image is the mask I want to apply.

[image: Correct mask]

The background must be transparent, so I can't just use white to create a fake mask.

Edit: Replacing `href` with `xlink:href` makes the arrows appear, but the outer circle is still missing. (In Inkscape the circle is there but it isn't masked.)

[image: Different broken SVG]

Comment: *However, if I open it as an SVG file* What does that mean? You've not defined the SVG namespace so it's not a valid SVG XML file. You may also need to use xlink:href instead of href

Comment: I'd hae probably drawn the circle with stroke-dasharray rather than a mask. Is that a solution to simply draw the shape differently and more simply?

Comment: That looks like it could work. How would I create an dasharray identical to the masked circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the mask altogether and drawn the circle with a stroke-dasharray and rotated it so the gaps are in the right places.

This is much more efficient as there's no raster mask operation.

```html
<svg width="256" height="256">
  <defs>
<g id="symmetry">
  <polygon points="128 124 116 100 124 100 124 56 132 56 132 100 140 100 128 124"/>
  <polygon points="96 29 160 29 160 24 96 24"/>
  <polygon points="96 24 120 24 120 19 96 19" transform="rotate(100, 96, 24)"/>
  <polygon points="136 24 160 24 160 19 136 19" transform="rotate(-100, 160, 24)"/>
</g>
  </defs>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (0, 128, 128)"/>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (120, 128, 128)"/>
  <use href="#symmetry" transform="rotate (240, 128, 128)"/>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="56" stroke="black" stroke-width="12" fill="none"/>
  <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="88" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="118.3 66" transform="rotate(51.4, 128, 128)"/>
</svg>
```

Exact values courtesy of Paul LeBeau

There are 3 key numbers here, the stroke-dasharray values that must add to 2 x PI / 3 (because of the 3 fold symmetry) and the first rotate value. You can play with the numbers till you get a perfect result but the values above are pretty good.

Comment: There's a small error where the dasharray meets the outdented section. Is it possible to make sure they align perfectly?

Comment: I know, but I need it to fit perfectly. Maybe I can use some geometry to calculate the exact point. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: sum of dasharray values = 2 x pi x r / 3 (because there are 3 segments)

Comment: It doesn't seem like this will work. I can't get it to precisely line up properly. :-(

Comment: Try `stroke-dasharray="118.3 66" transform="rotate(51.4, 128, 128)"`

Comment: It's still _very slightly_ off.

Comment: However, I'll still accept the answer. It's close enough.

Comment: I came up with those values on Chrome on Windows. Other browsers on other operating systems may produce slightly different results.  If you want it perfect, then I would suggest redrawing it so that the circle and the three notches are a single path.